# Gnome is opened inside folders after -config x-terminal-emulator has changed

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Hello guys I like working with Tilix terminal because of the multi panels. 
I have used

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

to change the terminal and it works fine on the Desktop but when I try it inside a folder it opens again Gnome. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour since Nautilus relies on a package called `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` for "Open in Terminal" option instead of x-terminal-emulator.

Comment: How did you install tilix? I use the budgie desktop (which has tilix as the default terminal emulator out of the box) and it provides its own shortcut via `/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/open-tilix.py` (apparently part of the `tilix-common` package)

Comment: For installing Tilix I followed the instructions from here https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/01/tilix-terminal-app-new-update-icon